# Classes and textbox is not a member of class generate

Tags: vb.net

Hello i'm trying to move my code to difrent classes so i can keep everything organized.

What i have now:

```
    Public Async Sub GenButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GenButton.Click
    Dim tasks As New List(Of Task)()
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(AddressOf generate))
    Await Task.WhenAll(tasks)
    generatedlines.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath & "\Generated" & Me.NumericUpDown3.Value & ".txt")
    Me.generatedlines.Lines = Me.generatedlines.Lines.Distinct.ToArray
    generatedlines.SaveFile(Application.StartupPath & "\Generated" & Me.NumericUpDown3.Value & ".txt", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
    MessageBox.Show("lines generated in Generated" & Me.NumericUpDown3.Value & ".txt", "Task Completed!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
End Sub
```

What i want:

```
   Public Class Form1
Public Async Sub GenButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GenButton.Click
//run code of class generate
end sub
   end class


public class generate
    Dim tasks As New List(Of Task)()
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(AddressOf generate))
    Await Task.WhenAll(tasks)
    generatedlines.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath & "\Generated" & Me.NumericUpDown3.Value & ".txt")
    Me.generatedlines.Lines = Me.generatedlines.Lines.Distinct.ToArray
    generatedlines.SaveFile(Application.StartupPath & "\Generated" & Me.NumericUpDown3.Value & ".txt", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
    MessageBox.Show("lines generated in Generated" & Me.NumericUpDown3.Value & ".txt", "Task Completed!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
end class
```

I tried this before but it will give errors like "generatedlines is not a member of class generated"

Comment: You need to put that code in a function or a method.

Comment: Ok, thanks will try once this is done.

Comment: I don't know what that means.